# How do I asynchronously rejoin the original Thread on completion?

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin, completable-future

Although I don't think of this as a Vaadin Specific question. All I really need to do is rejoin the thread that the future creates on completion.

```
(ClickHandler) (event) -> {
    log().debug( "current Thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId() );
    viewModel.generateFileDownload().thenAccept( this::download );
    // needs to continue to this immediately, note: there are similarly vaadin reasons why you can't just block here.
    button.setEnabled( false );
}


private void download( final File file ) {
   // do stuff that needs to happen in the original thread
  log().debug( "current Thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId() );

   button.setEnabled( true );
}
```

I need these thread id's to be the same, obviously I can rework this. I know there's a join, but now sure how that helps me when I don't want to rejoin until completion?

Comment: Well you can't. 'Joining' a thread has a different meaning from what you're talking about. The callback runs in its own thread. If there is stuff that needs to be done in the originating thread you need to be using a Future-style interface, not a completion callback.

Comment: @EJP and how would I do that?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem you should simply use

```
Button button = new Button("Download");
button.setDisableOnClick(true); //after creating the button
```

and

```
button.setEnabled(true); //after using the button, in click handler
```

Note that this is a feature in `Button`. For more advanced cases you should use `@Push` feature of Vaadin.